# Stop a slideshow with setTimeout by mouseover, start by mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, slideshow, mouseover

I would like to stop the following "Slideshow with setTimeout" by mouseover of elements with the class ".imageWrapper" - start by mouseout. Thank you all for your help!

Here's the script:

```
let showNextPictureGalleryImageTimeout;

$(document).on("click", ".picture-gallery .images img", function() {

    clearTimeout(showNextPictureGalleryImageTimeout);

    const pictureGallery = $(this).closest(".picture-gallery");
    const images = $('.images', pictureGallery);
    const activeImage = $(this);

    $('img', images).removeClass('active');
    activeImage.addClass('active');

    $(".title", pictureGallery).html("");

    const currentActiveImage = $(".fullshow img", pictureGallery);
    if(currentActiveImage.length === 0) {

        $(".fullshow", pictureGallery).append(activeImage.clone());
        $(".title", pictureGallery).html(activeImage.attr("title"));
    } else {

        currentActiveImage.fadeTo(400,0.30, function() {
            currentActiveImage.attr("src", activeImage.attr("src"));
            currentActiveImage.attr("title", activeImage.attr("title"));
        }).fadeTo(400,1, function() {
            $(".title", pictureGallery).html(activeImage.attr("title"));
        });
    }

    showNextPictureGalleryImageTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

        let nextActiveImage = $('img', activeImage.closest('.imageWrapper').next());
        if(nextActiveImage.length === 0) {
            nextActiveImage = $('img', $('.imageWrapper', pictureGallery).first());
        }

        nextActiveImage.trigger('click');
    }, 8000);
});
```

I tried this code:

```
let showNextPictureGalleryImageTimeout;

$(document).on("click", ".picture-gallery .images img", function() {

    clearTimeout(showNextPictureGalleryImageTimeout);

    const pictureGallery = $(this).closest(".picture-gallery");
    const images = $('.images', pictureGallery);
    const activeImage = $(this);

    $('img', images).removeClass('active');
    activeImage.addClass('active');

    $(".title", pictureGallery).html("");

    const currentActiveImage = $(".fullshow img", pictureGallery);
    if(currentActiveImage.length === 0) {

        $(".fullshow", pictureGallery).append(activeImage.clone());
        $(".title", pictureGallery).html(activeImage.attr("title"));
    } else {

        currentActiveImage.fadeTo(400,0.30, function() {
            currentActiveImage.attr("src", activeImage.attr("src"));
            currentActiveImage.attr("title", activeImage.attr("title"));
        }).fadeTo(400,1, function() {
            $(".title", pictureGallery).html(activeImage.attr("title"));
        });
    }

    $('.imageWrapper img').mouseover(function(){
    clearIntervall(showNextPictureGalleryImageTimeout);
    }).mouseout(function(){
       showNextPictureGalleryImageTimeout = setIntervall(function() {

       let nextActiveImage = $('img', activeImage.closest('.imageWrapper').next());
       if(nextActiveImage.length === 0) {
           nextActiveImage = $('img', $('.imageWrapper', pictureGallery).first());
       }

       nextActiveImage.trigger('click');
       }, 8000);
    });
});
```

Sorry, I can't program at all. I thought it might be a very simple snippet of code from which I can learn something for the future.

Comment: Did you try to implement this feature? If so can you add the code that did not work?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I pasted the code I tried into the main question.

Comment: onclick you will bind more and more event handlers. They will start piling up. $('.imageWrapper img').mouseover will not replace the previous events you already addded.